# How to set 'NO_API_ACCESS_TO_RECEIVER' permission via PayPal Adaptive API

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm using PayPal's adaptive payment API. Now, there is a case when I need to take money back from receiver. When I tried 'Refund' API, then I got the error: `NO_API_ACCESS_TO_RECEIVER` in `refundStatus` field. I know that this is permission related issue and to fix this problem, receiver needs to grant permission from his PayPal account. But we can't rely on receiver to give the permission. So, I'm looking for a way, by which we can set this permission via API and will pass that approval key with the refund request. Currently, I've searched and found that we can't pass `preapprovalKey` with the refund request but I want something like this. So, please suggest me how can I make it possible via Adaptive API, so that I can complete the refund process. Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask